# Postman + Flask Sending large file stalls

Tags: flask, postman

I'm a flask newby, using postman to POST a 572 KB, 57 page pdf file to my flask api. In the api I'm using `file = request.files['file']` to get the file from the request object:

```
 print("running try block")

 file = request.files['file']

 print('file', file)
```

The program hangs at `file = request.files['file']` but works fine when only sending 1 page. Are there known file size restrictions on either the postman or the flask side that I should take into consideration?

[image]

Comment: Just compressed to just below 500kb and it works